# URL not working using JSOUP 400 error

Tags: jsoup

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class JSoupExampleForJDPA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document document;
        String url = "http://scripting.jdpoweronline.com/mrIWeb/mrIWeb.dll?I.Project=T1_QTYPE&i.test=1";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get(url);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();

            if (i == 0) {
                document =Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true)

                          .timeout(60 * 1000)
                          .userAgent("Mozilla")
                          .cookie("auth", "token")
                          .timeout(3000)
                          .get();
            } else {

                document = Jsoup.connect(currentUrl).ignoreContentType(true)
                          .timeout(60 * 1000)
                          .userAgent("Mozilla")
                          .cookie("auth1", "token1")
                          .timeout(3000)
                          .get();
            }

            Elements elements = document.select("a");

            System.out.println("******************* currentUrl " + currentUrl + "*******************");
            if (!elements.isEmpty()) {
                for (Element elementsIterator : elements) {
                    String href = elementsIterator.attr("href");
                    System.out.println("a[href=" + '"' + href + '"' + "]");
                }
            }


            if (i == 0) {
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mrNext")).click();

            } else if (i == 1) {
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#_Q0_C0")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mrNext")).click();
            } 
            else if (i == 2) {
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#_Q1_C0")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mrNext")).click();
            } 

        }
    }

}

This is my code. Here i am opening URL (as given) with driver.get() method of Selenium.
Also i wanted to get all HREF tags present on current page. So I am doing this using Jsoup.connect() method. In for loops, navigating to next page. Problem is that i am getting HREF tags of 1st page only not of next pages. URL not working when i copy paste in another tab.
```

I got following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL=http://scripting.jdpoweronline.com/mrIWeb/mrIWeb.dll#4
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)
    at publicc.JSoupExampleForJDPA.main(JSoupExampleForJDPA.java:41)
```

Comment: Try to explain what are you trying to do first, instead of throwing some code

Comment: I want to collect all link tags on current page. I have to do this for all pages when i click on next page. Means after clicking on next page(which i am doing in for loop) i want to collect all link tags for that page also

Answer (score 0):

This url -> http://scripting.jdpoweronline.com/mrIWeb/mrIWeb.dll#4

returns the 400 error. Click it and check the server response. Try to find
which page contains this url. You could just avoid parsing urls that end with `dll#<number>` altogether.